# Evaluating $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the value of
$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2-y^2}$$
I have already tried the two paths result and I think now that the limit does exist and it is equals to 0. But i really cannot prove this.

Comment: Similar one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4325565/977780

Comment: It's a duplicate.Does this answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219144/977780

Comment: Restrict $|x|<1$ and let $y^2=x^2+\frac1k x^3$, where $k>1$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{xy^2}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{x(x^2+\frac1k x^3)}{-\frac1k x^3}=-x-k$$

Inasmuch as the limit depends on $k$, the limit fails to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, we can calculate that the expression following the limit is
$$
r \frac{\cos\theta \sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta} = r \frac{\cos\theta}{\cot^2\theta - 1}
$$
We can make $r$ as small as we want as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, but we can also make $\frac{\cos\theta}{\cot^2 \theta - 1}$ as big as we want no matter how small $r$ is (how?). Can you see how to use this to prove that the limit does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

In Polar Co-ordinates , we get $x = r\cos(\theta)$ & $y = r\sin(\theta)$

Plugging that into given limit , we get $r^3$ term in $xy^2$ & $r^2$ term in $x^2-y^2$

Then the limit is $r[f(\theta)]$ where $f$ is function of $\theta$ , in terms of $\cos$ & $\sin$

Here $f(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)}$

When $\theta=0,\pi/2,\pi$ , we have $f=0$
When $\theta=\pi/4$ , we have $\cos^2(\theta) = \sin^2(\theta)$ , hence $f$ is unbounded ($1/0$)

Depending on the Path to (0,0) , we get various values of the term. Hence , the limit will not exist !

Thanks to user @CharlesHudgins & user @MathFail who Pointed out the right way.

Comment: This is not universally true. We need for $f$ to be a bounded function of $\theta$.

Comment: Oh ok , I guess I have to actually calculate $f$ here.

Comment: I have "updated" that , @MathFail

Comment: My "assumption" about $f(\theta)$ was wrong , thank you for Pointing that out , @CharlesHudgins

Answer (score 0):

> $$L=\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2-y^2}$$

$$L=\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2-x^3+x^3}{x^2-y^2}=\lim_{x \to0} (-x)+\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x^3}{x^2-y^2}=\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x^3}{x^2-y^2}$$

Let $y=x-ax^2$

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3}{2ax^3-a^2x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2a-a^2x}=\frac{1}{2a}$$

So the limit depends on the value of $a$, hence the limit doesn't exist.